# Restrict subnet access based on LDAP group

Tags: vpn, openvpn, access-control-list

I've got 3 VLANs: Server, IT and Staff. The Staff VLAN has restricted access to the Server VLAN, while the IT VLAN has access to everything.

When someone connects to the VPN I'd like to give them similar permissions based on whether they're in the Staff or IT LDAP groups.

Is this possible with OpenVPN? How would it be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You're messing entinies due to lack of understanding of OSI model. You should restrict login access to these servers basing on the user's group, not the connectivity to their subnets. The connectivity from VPN should be restricted globally, for all of the VPN subnetworks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Only the IT group has login permissions to the servers. As an extra layer of protection I have an ACL on the main switch blocking access to anyone who isn't in the IT VLAN/Subnet. I'd like to do the same thing for VPN connections, or anyone who connects through OpenVPN will be able to try their luck logging in to the servers.